# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with hive

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, netbeans, hive

I used hadoop hive 0.9.0 and 1.1.2 and netbeans,
but I got this error and I can not solve this problem
please help me
code :

```
public class Hive_test {

private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

   @SuppressWarnings("CallToThreadDumpStack")
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
            System.out.println("commencer la connexion");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default",""," ");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from STATE");
    while (res.next()){
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
                    System.out.println("sql terminer");
    }
}
```

Error below;

```
error :
commencer la connexion
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:353)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.recv_execute(ThriftHive.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.execute(ThriftHive.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at hive.Hive_test.main(Hive_test.java:22)
```

Comment: Did you try with more memory  ?  with -Xmx ?

Comment: @Jayan no I do not know how, because I work netbeans

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the container heapsize in Hive and resolve this error:

Most tools that operate on top of the Hadoop MapReduce framework provide ways to tune these Hadoop level settings for its jobs.  There are multiple ways to do this in Hive.  Three of these are shown here:

1) Pass it directly via the Hive command line:

```
hive -hiveconf mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5120 -e "select count(*) from test_table;"
```

2) Set the ENV variable before invoking Hive:

```
export HIVE_OPTS="-hiveconf mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5120"
```

3) Use the "set" command within the hive CLI.

```
hive> set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096;
hive> set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5120;
hive> select count(*) from test_table;
```

Comment: how i can set the container heapsize in Hive, i use netbeans please help me

Comment: this setting won't help fot java GC overhead limit error, am I correcT?

Answer (score 6):

Well, in my case, I also need to set memory in `java.opts`

```
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3686m;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=4096;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx3686m;
```

Answer (score 5):

For me the below solution works.

Before starting the hive CLI use `export  HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=" -Xmx8192m"` and then launch the cli