# Hive Union all and aggregation operation on large parquet tables (150 columns and 5 million rows) failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I have following query with 2 parquet tables (t_par_string, t_par_datatype).

```
 select count(*)                                
  from (                                
        select max(source) source,    
              col1, col2, col3 
              .
              .
              .
              col149,col150 , count(*)                  
          from (                                
                select 1 source, 
                   col1, col2, col3 
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   col149,col150  
                from t_par_string
                union all                               
                select 1 source, 
                   col1, col2, col3 
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   col149,col150  
                from t_par_datatype
               ) merged_data                                
        group by                                    
            col1, col2, col3 
            .
            .
            .
            col149,col150                   
        having count(*) = 1                             
       ) minus_data                             
 where source = 1
```

It is failed with following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString@134ff8f8 of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString with arguments {2015-10-17 00:00:00:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable} of size 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:497)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:965)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.copyMembers(DateFormatSymbols.java:850)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.initializeData(DateFormatSymbols.java:758)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.<init>(DateFormatSymbols.java:145)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DateFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getProviderInstance(DateFormatSymbols.java:364)
    at java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(DateFormatSymbols.java:340)
    at java.util.Calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.java:2110)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:1125)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:966)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable.toString(TimestampWritable.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString.evaluate(UDFToString.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:965)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
```

Comment: `count()`? .............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673053/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-with-hive)